# use props to change height of class

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I work with `Vue 3` and `Bootstrap 5`. I have a `props` called `number` (get me integers from 1 - 10).

Now I want to work with with my `number` in my `scrollbar`-class.

I've tried as following but it's not working. I get no error - it's simply not working.

How can I fix that? Thank You!

```
<template>
  <div class="scrollbar"
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      number: Number,
    }
  }
</script>
```

```
<style>
  .scrollbar {
    height: calc(500px + (var(--number) * 20 px));
  }
</style>
```

Comment: `var(--number)` is a [css custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) and is not affected by the JS in the current example.

Comment: But how can I work with my ```prop``` - i actually could not figure it out..

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#props

Answer (score 2):

You can use [v-bind](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css) in your `<style>` tag to bind a data property to your CSS.

It will also reactivly update, if your state changes.

```html
<template>
  <div class="scrollbar">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      number: Number,
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  .scrollbar {
    height: calc(500px + (v-bind(number) * 20px));
  }
</style>
```

[Demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)